# Can an AWS EC2 instance connect to a VPN of a remote network without using AWS VPN services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to connect an ec2 instance to a VPN on a remote network without configuring the VPN connection on the entire VPC where the ec2 instance exists?

I want to create the VPN connection inside the ec2 instance instead of setting up AWS Site-to-Site VPN on the VPC.

Until now I have tried two different ways of creating the VPN connection inside the ec2 instance which is running on ubuntu and none of the ways worked. I tried the exact same VPN connection configurations on the same ubuntu version but on my local machine and both of them worked. I am wondering if what I am trying to achieve is possible or not without using an AWS VPN service (or 3rd party) that creates a VPN connection between the remote network and the VPC where the ec2 exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use.

To work, the EC2 instance must:

- be running on a **public subnet**, ie directly connected to an internet gateway and have a public IP address;
- ports must be allowed in the **security group** - pay attention if the connection uses **UDP or TCP** and if there are **outbound rules** that match your configuration.

This guide using OpenVPN might help a quick test.
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/static-key-mini-howto/